# Android client not receiving socket.io message from node.js server

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have connected an Android Client to a node.js server using socket.io and i am able to send messages to the server but not receive on the client. 
For the client side i do somthing like

```
Log.i("MainActivity: ", "sending message");
    final JSONObject sdpObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        sdpObj.put("id","presenter");
        sdpObj.put("sdpOffer",localSdpOffer.description);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LoginActivity.mSocket.emit("new message", sdpObj);
```

and on the server i receive the object like:

```
 io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){

        socket.on('new message',function(message){
              // some logic
          socket.emit('created',object);
```

then on the client side:

```
     LoginActivity.mSocket.on("created", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.i( TAG, "message back:received ");

            User user = new User();
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = new JSONObject((String) args[0]);
                //Log.i(TAG,"SdpAnswer: "+args[0].sdpAnswer+"id "+obj.sdpAnswer);

            Log.i(TAG, "Instance of"+args[0].toString());
        }
    });
}
```

But for some reason it never receives the message.
Anyone have some ideas why that may be? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i figured it out after some more searching. It seems that in order to maintain correctly the socket connection for different android activities I had to implement a singleton class where i have defined the socket connection.The problem was that i instantiated the socket connection in one activity and tried to use that connection on another and even if I could send messages on another activity I could not receive any unless I moved the socket to the activities where the messages where received. You can find a lot of examples on how to implement a singleton class so it's not to hard and it solved my problem. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the socket.io library by nkzawa as per the docs you have to process the internals of the call method using a runonUIThread method.

```
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;

private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object.. args) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                String username;
                String message;
                try {
                    username = data.getString("username");
                    message = data.getString("message");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return;
                }

                // add the message to view
                addMessage(username, message);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This is what onNewMessage looks like. A listener is an instance of Emitter.Listener and must be implemented the call method. You’ll notice that inside of call() is wrapped by Activity#runOnUiThread(), that is because the callback is always called on another thread from Android UI thread, thus we have to make sure that adding a message to view happens on the UI thread.

Refer to this link for more info:
[Native Socket.IO and Android](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

Comment: I could not agree that in above sample runOnUiThread is required. There is no manipulation of any view. And in my opinion this is the reason why is required on Socket.IO site sample.